# Choosing appropriate RFID devices for a project

Tags: nfc, rfid

I'm currently working on a project using RFID. I'm programmer but have no clue about hardware, so a little help would be appreciated :)

Here is the project :

A place is filled with RFID tags with lowest range (Low frequency, 125 kHz) coming in pairs. Every pair of tags should contain the informations : tag_id + (first / second)

Multiple users are in the room, each will have a wrist handling RFID reader (which i’ll call “watch” for convenience) and will use it to read as much pair of tags as possible. 
The history of which tags have been read should be stored in the watch for the duration of the “run”

Example of a run :

- User read tag 1-first
- User read tag 1-second
- User read tag 2-first
- User read tag 3-first (because he can’t find the 2-second, so he goes on)
  etc..

Once one user has finished his “run”, we have to collect the informations stored on the watch. The best way would be to have a collecting device in the room, on which you would just have to put your watch so that the datas are collected and flushed so that the watch is instantly usable by another user.
The datas are then used to feed a database, so the collecting device is likely to be a computer (i.e. a raspberry pi)

**Questions :**

1. What kind of technology could be used to do the “collecting device” and how could it collect datas / flush datas from the watches ?
2. What kind of device could be the “watch” ?
3. I went straight to RFID technology as it seemed to be appropriate for the usage, but any better proposition would be welcome
4. Bonus : Would it be possible to get the time between first tag scan and second tag scan for every pair to store the delay for every pair at the end. And does it imply a change in the kind of device used for the watch ?

Constraints :
The tags has to be as cheap as possible (<1€) as it will be changed regularly
The watch has to be small, neither bigger nor heavier than a real watch.
The watch should be a cheap device (< 50€)
The watch has to emit a beep when scanning a tag to ensure the user that the tag has been correctly read

Thanks for your feedbacks ;)